# Declaration merging not working

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use a property that is not declared in the "official" typescript declaration.

```
import Map = require("esri/map");
....
private static obtainMapLayers(map: Map) {
   let info = map.itemInfo; // Error: Property 'iteminfo' does not exist on type 'Map'
}
```

I have tried to follow [this](https://justintimecoder.com/how-to-polyfil-missing-types-in-typescript/) guide on declaration merging, but `itemInfo` is still not resolving.

The `Map` type as declared by `@types/arcgis-js-api`:

```
declare module "esri/map" {
  import esri = require("esri");
  ...

  class Map {
    attribution: Attribution;
    autoResize: boolean;
    ...
  }
  export = Map;
}
```

I have created an `index.d.ts` file in `./typings` folder with the following:

```
declare module "esri/map" {

  class Map {
    itemInfo: any;
  }
  export = Map;
}
```

Any ideas why the declarations are not being merged?

Comment: Is anything else in your `index.d.ts` working? Is it possible that `./typings` isn't included in your `tsconfig`

Comment: If I rename my declaration that I want to merge e.g. `declare module "esriii/map"` and `class Mapii`, etc. and import this `import Mapii = require("esriii/map");`, the `itemInfo` property is recognized in the `Mapii` object.  So, the declaration in `typings` is being picked up.  I just can't merge this with the 3rd party declaration.